# How to handle mail handling with php

Tags: php, html, forms

I've been having some issues setting up an email sending form in html using php. The error I get is as such:

**Cannot POST /public/mail_handler.php**

I'm not certain where the problem is arising from. Here's the html:

```
    <form id="appt" action="/public/mail_handler.php" method="POST">

        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name..."> <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name..."> <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email..."> <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Callback Number..."> <br>
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="New"> Schedule an appointment regarding making a computer <br>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Old"> Call about a computer we made <br>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Current"> Ask about the status of your build <br>
        <input type="radio" name="type" value="Other"> Have a question about something else <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

And the php:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$to = $_POST['email'];
$from = "ajippov@gmail.com"; 
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = "Testing"; 
$body = "This is a test"; 

mail($to, $subject, $body); 

echo "Request has been sent"; 


}
?>
```

Comment: Do you need to echo back? Do you have mail server up and running?

Comment: Seems like a lot you are not telling us.  There are 7 forms in your html, but none of them has an action of `mail_handler.php` (only 1 of them has a method).  `Cannot POST /public/mail_handler.php` does not sound like a PHP or Javascript or Apache error ... what is the *exact* error, and how do you generate it?

Comment: I posted the wrong form; the code above is still giving me the message: Cannot POST /public/mail_handler.php, when I hit the submit button.

Comment: where dose the error text appear? JS-Console, inside the Browser window, inside a apache log-file ...

Comment: It appears in the browser window after the submit button is pressed.